# How do I recode values in a table based on frequency of the value

Tags: r

I'm trying to recode values with freq = 1 to the next band.

Using iris dataset as an example.

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length) %>% table %>% as.data.frame()
```

We can see from the table that the values 7.9, 7.6, 7.4, 7.3, 7.1, 7, 5.3, 4.3 have frequencies of 1.

Currently, I'm manually recoding the single frequencies to the next lower band and the smallest band to the on above it.

```
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "7.9"] = "7.7"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "7.6"] = "7.4"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "7.3"] = "7.2"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "7.1"] = "7"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "5.3"] = "5.2"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "4.5"] = "4.4"
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length == "4.3"] = "4.4"
```

Would like to seek your advice on how to write a function which does the following:

1. Check each value from the biggest value downwards for Freq = 1
2. When a value with Freq = 1 is identified, mutate it's value to the next lower value.
3. Repeat the Check from the top.
4. If the last value (Smallest value) has Freq = 1, mutate it's value to the next higher value.
5. Finish the function when there are no more Freq = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could count, sort, lag, and then manually fix the smallest band.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- iris %>%
  add_count(Sepal.Length) %>%
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate(new_variable = if_else(n == 1, lag(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Length))

dat$new_variable[1] <- dat$new_variable[2]

head(dat)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species n new_variable
#> 1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa 1          4.4
#> 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa 3          4.4
#> 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa 3          4.4
#> 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 3          4.4
#> 5          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa 1          4.4
#> 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 4          4.6
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. It works for my need. thank you!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it fits your needs.